# Optimizing MySQL "IN" Select?

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    `influencers`.*,
    `locations`.`country_name`
FROM
    `influencers`
    LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `influencers`.`country_id` = `locations`.`id`
WHERE
    `is_dead` = 0
    AND `influencers`.`is_private` = 0
    AND `influencers`.`country_id` = '31'
    AND influencers.uuid IN(
        SELECT
            `influencer_uuid` FROM `category_influencer`
        WHERE
            `category_influencer`.`category_id` = 17
            AND `category_influencer`.`is_main` = 1)
ORDER BY
    `influencers`.`followed_by` DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 6
```

I have identified the IN subquery is causing a lag of around 10s for this query to complete. Here is the **EXPLAIN**:

[image: MySQL Explain]

I have indexes on all columns being queried.

**How can I significantly speed this query up?**

Updated with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both:

**`locations`**

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`city_name`, `country_name`),
    KEY `type` (`type`)
    USING BTREE) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6479 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
```

**`influencers`**

```
CREATE TABLE `influencers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `bio` varchar(255) CHARACTER
    SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
    `url` varchar(255) CHARACTER
    SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
    `followed_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `follows` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `full_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER
    SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `social_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_private` tinyint (1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `text_search` text CHARACTER
    SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_dead` tinyint (4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
    UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
    KEY `is_dead` (`is_dead`),
    KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`),
    KEY `followed_by` (`followed_by`),
    KEY `social_id` (`social_id`),
    KEY `is_private` (`is_private`),
    KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `text_search` (`text_search`)) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2278376 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

Comment: Prepend each column with the table (or better, with the alias of the table) where it belongs to. It may be obvious to you where each column is, but not to us.

Comment: Also please show us the code for the indexes.

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query performance always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: @TheImpaler I have prepended the columns above

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the in clause using an inner join

```
    SELECT
        `influencers`.*,
        `locations`.`country_name`
    FROM
        `influencers`
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT
                `influencer_uuid` FROM `category_influencer`
            WHERE
                `category_id` = 17
                AND `is_main` = 1

    ) T ON T.influencer_uuid = influencers.uuid
        LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `influencers`.`country_id` = `locations`.`id`
    WHERE
        `is_dead` = 0
        AND `is_private` = 0
        AND `country_id` = '31'

    ORDER BY
        `followed_by` DESC
    LIMIT 7 OFFSET 6
```

This way instead of an iteration on all the IN result you use just a single relational match  based  on join

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, you can replace the subselect with JOIN:

```
SELECT influencers.*,
       locations.country_name
FROM influencers
         JOIN category_influencer T ON (
            T.influencer_uuid = influencers.uuid
            AND category_id = 17
            AND is_main = 1)
         LEFT JOIN locations ON influencers.country_id = locations.id
WHERE is_dead = 0
  AND is_private = 0
  AND country_id = '31'

ORDER BY followed_by DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 6
```

Comment: Thanks but this still takes 13 secs to execute, but takes less than 1 sec if I remove the querying of ```category_influencer```. The strangest thing is there are indexes on each of the ```category_influencer``` columns that get queried - really not sure how to optimize this?